# How to access value of child model inside nested attributes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models `post` and `sign` like this.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :signs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :signs
end

class Sign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And I use `nested_form` gem, and this is form for `post`

```
<%= nested_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :signs do |sign| %>
  <%= render 'sign_fields', :f => sign %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And this is `_sign_fields.html.erb`.

```
<div class="sign">
    <%= image_tag "#{"%02d" % @post.signs[f.options[:child_index].to_i].image_number}.jpg" %>
</div>
```

It works though, I think there is a better way than `@post.signs[f.options[:child_index].to_i].image_number`.

How can I access the attributes of child model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
f.object.image_number
```

Comment: I replaced `@post.signs[f.options[:child_index].to_i].image_number` to `f.object.image_number`, then I got a error `can't convert nil into Integer`.

Comment: That means at least one of the `Sign` object's `image_number` is `nil`

Comment: You are right, the "add" tag created new Sign instance like `<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %></p>`. That caused the problem.